# pandas dataframe: how to match on multiple index levels when doing arithmetic operations involving two dataframes

Tags: indexing, dataframe, match, pandas, hierarchical

I have a DataFrame with three levels on the main index:

```
from pandas import *
df_multi = DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,2), index = [['CF', 'CF', 'CF', 'DA', 'DA','DA'], ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'y'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b']], columns = ['PC1', 'PC2'])
df_multi.index.names =['l1','l2','l3']

In [5]: df_multi
Out[5]: 
       PC1       PC2
l1 l2 l3                    
CF x  a   0.118061  0.473159
   y  b   0.159534  0.407676
      a   0.466731  0.163322
DA x  a   0.152799  0.333438
   y  a   0.632725  0.965348
      b   0.737112  0.834592
```

Now I want to sum across the third level and then divide each element by its corresponding sum to get shares at the third level (e.g. divide `(CF, x, a)` by `(CF, x, a)` and `(CF, y, a)` by `(CF, y, a) + (CF, y, b)`, etc.)

```
In [6]: df_multi.sum(level = [0, 1])
Out[6]: 
    PC1       PC2
l1 l2                    
CF x   0.118061  0.473159
   y   0.626265  0.570998
DA x   0.152799  0.333438
   y   1.369837  1.799940
```

and

```
df_multi_share = df_multi.div(df_multi.sum(level = [0, 1]), level=[0, 1])
```

However this does not work. I am looking for a general solution, not confined to the computation of percentage shares, that enables me to do arithmetics matching on multiple levels. It does work when using only one level, e.g.

```
df_multi = DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), index = [['CF', 'CF', 'DA', 'DA'], ['1', '2', '1', '2']], columns = ['PC1', 'PC2'])

df_single = DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), index = ['1', '2', '3'], columns = ['PC1', 'PC2', 'PC3'])

df_combined = df_multi.mul(df_single, level = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for `transform`.

```
df_multi.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

The relevant documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation

Comment: Thanks, Allan. I looked more into .apply and .transform. However it seems that this allows to execute functions at the group level. It is a solution for my particular case. I would be happy however to find a more general solution that allows me to add for instance dataframe1 and dataframe2 where I match not only one one level of multi indices, but on multiple levels. E.g. dataframe1 has 3 levels, dataframe2 has two levels, and I want to add the two dataframes, matching the two levels of dataframe2 with the second and third level of dataframe1 and broadcast along the first level of dataframe1.